# How do I get my leave approved from manager for my cousin’s wedding?

Tags: leave, leave-of-absence

I want to ask my manager for leave but I’m not sure if he’ll approve it.
Or is there any other reason I should provide so that my leave gets approved?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to find out is to ask.

Going to a wedding is a fairly strong justification so just stick with that.

When asking for leave, sooner is better so do it as soon as possible.

The only exception would be if your boss is in a really bad mood or something then maybe you should give it a few hours/a day or so to see if you can find a better moment.

Answer (score 0):

I mean - unless you've got a difficult boss or your company is in the middle of peak productivity time or you have no leave allowance outstanding - attending a Wedding is normally a pretty easy leave approval.

Just ask normally.

"Can you approve this leave on this day? I'm going to be attending a Wedding"

Failing that, if you are in a work environment where Leave is often denied for frivolous reasons or they are generally difficult - you can go with the direct approach:

"On this day, I am going to be attending a Family members Wedding. I will not be in the office or available to work."

If your work is really difficult and unreasonable with trying to get leave - simply don't ask, and on the day of the wedding develop a nasty vomitting bug that leaves you out of action for 24 hours (not long enough for a Doctors note to be required)

Comment: "**simply don't ask, and on the day of the wedding develop a nasty vomitting bug that leaves you out of action for 24 hours**" - Do you mean to say the OP should make up a fake excuse just to go to a wedding ? Or do you mean to say the OP should get ill physically for real (if yes, how can the OP go to a wedding if he is ill) ? -- BTW, I did not downvote this answer.

Comment: I'm suggesting that if the company never approves leave and is borderline illegal - then you should pull a sicky.